# Numpy matshow produces blank image despite dtype is float

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, imshow

I have script that takes 3 same size numpy array, create ndarray using dstack and suppose to display them as rgb image.However, the last part of the RGB image seems to be working but I cannot display the image and all I get is blank image.
This is how I create the image from 3 arrays:

```
rgb_result=np.dstack((result[3,:,:],result[2,:,:],result[1,:,:]))
    

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.matshow(rgb_result*5,fignum=1,aspect='auto')
plt.title(d)
plt.show()
```

The result is blank image:

[image]

whenever I plot one of the bands that constructs "rgb_result" it works (the three images are very similar to this):
[image]

I have also checked the dype of each band and of the ndarray, and it was float64.
**My question is how can I make matshow work and show the image in RGB.**

Comment: what are the `min()` and `max()` of your `rgb_result`? your code produces a proper rgb image when i tried with some random data, so i think we need to see an actual data sample that causes the issue (i didn't downvote)

Comment: @tdy max() is 0.0135 and min () is 0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`matshow`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.matshow.html#matplotlib.pyplot.matshow) uses [`imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow) under the hood, which expects the data to be between 0-1 for floats or 0-255 for ints:

> (M, N, 3): an image with RGB values (0-1 float or 0-255 int).

Since `rgb_result` contains floats, it should be normalized to 0-1 (subtract min and divide by max):

```
plt.matshow((rgb_result-rgb_result.min())/rgb_result.max(), fignum=1, aspect='auto')
```

Or if `rgb_result` is guaranteed to be positive, just divide by max:

```
plt.matshow(rgb_result/rgb_result.max(), fignum=1, aspect='auto')
```

---

With some fake data, this is the pre- and post-normalized output:

[image: pre- and post-normalized]